# How to remove rows that do not have more than 3 values in r?

Tags: r, row

this is my first time asking a question and hopefully I can get your help!
I need to remove rows that have values for only one or two genes using R

[image]

basically I need to get rid of 50S, ABCC8, and ACAT1 because these have a n<3.

My desired output is

[image]

thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: How do you get the number of genes from the code in the Genes column?

Comment: Also,  please do not include your data as an image.  We would have to type it all in again.  Instead, use `dput` to get a text version of the data that you can paste into your question.    If your data is too long,  try something like    `dput(head(MyData, 20))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will definitely keep that in mind when asking questions. It was my first time so I wasn't sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a data.frame, you can use `dplyr` package to do some manipulation. We can group the data by the `Genes` and `count` how many instances are there. Then we simply set the filter criteria to remove the records.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Genes=c('50S'   ,'abcb1' ,'abcb1' ,'abcb1' ,'ABCC8' ,'ABL'   ,'ABL'   ,'ABL'   ,'ABL'   ,'ACAT1' ,'ACAT1' ),
  Values=c(-0.627323448, -0.226358414, 0.347305901 ,0.371632631 ,0.099485307 ,0.078512979 ,-0.426643782, -1.060270668, -2.059157991, 0.608899174 ,-0.048795611)
)

#group, filter and join back to get subset the data
df %>% group_by(Genes) 
  %>% summarize(count=n()) 
  %>% filter(count>=3) 
  %>% inner_join(df) 
  %>% select(Genes,Values)
```

As per @Lamia's comments, it is possible to simplify it to just:

```
df %>% group_by(Genes) %>% filter(n()>=3)
```

Comment: You could simplify it this way: `df %>% group_by(Genes) %>% filter(n()>=3)`

Comment: As I was typing my answer out, I thought "there has to be a prettier way of doing this..." And here it is!

Answer (score 0):

```
# generating data
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3) # has n < 3!
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
z <- c(1 ,2, 3, NA, 5, 6)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

colsToKeep <- c() # making empty vector I will fill with column numbers
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) { # for every column
  if (sum(!is.na(df[,i]))>=3) { # if that column has greater than 3 valid values (i.e., ones that are not na...
colsToKeep <- c(colsToKeep, i) # then save that column number into this vector
  }
}

df[,colsToKeep] # then use that vector to call the columns you want
```

Note that R treats FALSE as 0 and TRUE as 1, so that is how the `sum()` function works here.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution by using `table`:

```
gene <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","D")
value <- c(seq(1,10,1))
df<-data.frame(gene,value)
df
  gene value
1    A     1
2    A     2
3    A     3
6    C     6
7    C     7
8    C     8
9    C     9

su<-data.frame(table(df$gene))
df_keep <-df[which(df$gene %in% su[which(su$Freq>2),1]),]
df_keep
  gene value
1    A     1
2    A     2
3    A     3
6    C     6
7    C     7
8    C     8
9    C     9
```